# Stacked value with line chart with highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I got an situation like this. I would like to using line chart to draw stacked value. I have tried google search but i can't find the solution.

For example: On date May/23 i got 3 values, i would like to display these on line-chart.
How could i achieve this? Does highcharts support to do this one. Please take a look at the link attach to clearer the question

[Stacked line chart image](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3NUAgD0tB0YUGZRTlVMNU82M00)

Addition info: Im using highcharts to do this one

Thanks for any comment or answer

Comment: you can achieve that with a normal line chart. just provide the data in the right order. example `[[x1, y1], [x1, y2], [x1, y3], [x2, y1], [x2, y2], [x2, y3]]`.

Comment: @RahulSharma
I did like you said, but it got an issue with tooltip, the chart only show tooltip for the top one, for example, [x1, y2], [x1, y3] will not show on tooltip

Comment: one (there might be more) way i can think of doing it is preprocessing the data to create data for tooltip. so what you can do is iterate through the data and create an object, like `var tooltipData = {"x1": "y1, y2, y3", "x2": "y1, y2, y3"}` and in the tooltip formatter you would have access to the actual x value of the point which could be used to get the string to be displayed from this object.

Comment: but have you even tried to look up into the [demos](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/) and [the manual](http://www.highcharts.com/docs)? normally this helps, if nothing else works.

Comment: What have you tried? What's your code look like? Do you have a fiddle or live example?

Comment: Regarding the tooltip, I would suggest using a scatter series instead of a line. Set the lineWidth in the plotOptions and it will plot just like a line series, but the tool tips are handled differently.  Example:  http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/c1o8Lwgv/

Answer (score 1):

Follow jlbriggs
I should use scatter-chart to achieve this one

> Regarding the tooltip, I would suggest using a scatter series instead of a line. Set the lineWidth in the plotOptions and it will plot just like a line series, but the tool tips are handled differently. Example: jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/c1o8Lwgv